# Steam link app for Chrome OS?

Tags: steam, google-chrome

I want to remote play games on a Chromebook streamed from a Windows PC. Is there a [Steam link](https://store.steampowered.com/steamlink/about/) app or extension for Chrome OS?

Answer (score 2):

Just download and install the Android app from the Play Store.

It is not yet officially [mentioned](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4415-USKX-8715) in the list of supported OSs, but it works.

The list of supported controllers are much more limited for Android: only Steamlink controller itself and the Microsoft XBox One S controller are supported.